# What does WITH FORMAT do on a DIFFERENTIAL backup?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I could find a lot of questions about this. [This is a really good question, exactly what i'm asking here.](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1238363-391-1.aspx)

Down there, a guys asks the question with:

> you can have compressed and uncompressed on the same drive, just not
>   the same media set (file).

I planning to create a simple backup routine where There's a full backup at night, and a differential backup each hour. But to use COMPRESSION in a differential backup, I need to use FORMAT. What does this mean?

> Use FORMAT carefully. Formatting any volume of a media set renders the
>   entire media set unusable. For example, if you initialize a single
>   tape belonging to an existing striped media set, the entire media set
>   is rendered useless.

I can't understand this. Every backup has a different name, and they're going to stay in the same drive. What am I going to format with this option?

Can I have:

```
FULL.BKP
DIFF1.DIFF( With compression,format)
DIFF2.DIFF( With compression,format)
DIFF3.DIFF( With compression,format)
DIFF4.DIFF( With compression,format)
DIFF5.DIFF( With compression,format)
```

in the same disk? Thanks.

Comment: What says you need to use `FORMAT` with `COMPRESSION`? Check this [msdn article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_pfe_blog/2010/08/09/backup-compression-behavior-when-appending-backups-to-an-existing-media-set/). I think you've mis-read that other question.

Comment: Are you ever writing multiple differential backups to the same physical file? Would you ever be writing both compressed and uncompressed differential backups to the same file? Or full and differentials to the same file? Why? I've been using SQL Server for, oh, 21 years and I have yet to write any type of backup statement with `FORMAT`. And yes I've always implemented native backups except for a brief, unsuccessful attempt with a 3rd party product 15 years ago.

Comment: Where exactly did `But to use COMPRESSION in a differential backup, I need to use FORMAT.` come from?

Comment: I was sure that I didn't need that. But for some reason, when i tried, I saw an error saying something like "the bla bla bla device was incorrectly formated. bla bla bla you need to use FORMAT." But now I tried, and everything is ok. I could backup a DIFF with only compression and DIFFERENTIAL. I have no Idea what was that.

Answer (score 4):

> But to use COMPRESSION in a differential backup, I need to use FORMAT.

I'm not sure why you think you need to use `FORMAT` at all. This works just fine, I end up with two different differential backup files, each about 80kb:

```
BACKUP DATABASE db TO DISK = 'c:\bk\dif1.bak' WITH COMPRESSION, DIFFERENTIAL;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE db TO DISK = 'c:\bk\dif2.bak' WITH COMPRESSION, DIFFERENTIAL;
```

As does writing both differentials to the same file (though I don't know why people like doing this), I end up with a single backup file that contains two differential backups, about 165kb:

```
BACKUP DATABASE db TO DISK = 'c:\bk\dif.bak' WITH COMPRESSION, DIFFERENTIAL;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE db TO DISK = 'c:\bk\dif.bak' WITH COMPRESSION, DIFFERENTIAL;
```

As does overwriting the same file each time, I end up with a single differential backup representing the *most recent* differential backup I took, about 80kb:

```
BACKUP DATABASE db TO DISK = 'c:\bk\dif.bak' WITH INIT, COMPRESSION, DIFFERENTIAL;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE db TO DISK = 'c:\bk\dif.bak' WITH INIT, COMPRESSION, DIFFERENTIAL;
```

All of these result in compressed differential backups, and I didn't use `FORMAT` once.

I don't have a 2008 R2 instance to test, and it might be the case that it is impossible in that version to - say - capture multiple diffs to the same backup file (what the documentation might call a media set, but that was more relevant back in that decade when we used tape drives) and take the first diff compression (or encryption, etc.) and the second one without. Compression on and off is fine in modern versions, though I didn't test encryption. In any case, you won't be in that situation if you make each backup its own file in the first place, which I think is what you should do.

This makes your question rather academic. But to answer it, for all intents and purposes, `FORMAT` on a differential backup effectively does the same thing as `INIT` - it wipes out any previous backups in the file. So with this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE db TO DISK = 'c:\bk\dif.bak' WITH INIT, COMPRESSION, DIFFERENTIAL;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE db TO DISK = 'c:\bk\dif.bak' WITH FORMAT, COMPRESSION, DIFFERENTIAL;
```

I end up with the same, single 80kb backup as if I had used `INIT` in both statements. All older backups in that file, regardless of format, except the last one, are removed.